# How can I check against an iOS specific devices in Xcode using Swift 3?

Tags: iphone, swift3, xcode8, ios10

I'm setting up a collection view and I was having trouble defining the correct size of the cells for each app size, so I decided to do it manually through flowLayout.itemSize.width and flowLayout.itemSize.height, but to do it that way I need to check against each device, like the iPhone 6/7 and iPhone 6/7 Plus to correctly setup the cell sizes. So, how do I check against the specific devices to solve my problem?

Comment: You don't need to get device, just use screenbound.size and make your items height/witdh with it

Answer (score 2):

So, that is pretty much the way I solved the problem. I first got the correct size of the width and height for every device, then I did a check based on it. Inside each conditional, I finish setting up the design of my collectionView cells.

func adjustPetCellDesign() {
        //Get the flowLayout to set margins for the petCell
        guard let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else { return }
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = margin
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = margin
        flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: margin, left: margin, bottom: margin, right: margin)

```
    //Get the screenSize to get width and height of every device.
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height

    //If iPhone is 6(s) or 7(s), set width and height as shown below
    if screenWidth == 375 && screenHeight == 667 {
        flowLayout.itemSize.height = 171.5
        flowLayout.itemSize.width = 171.5

        //If iPhone is 6(s)/7(s) Plus, set width and height as shown below
    } else if screenWidth == 414 && screenHeight == 736 {
        flowLayout.itemSize.height = 194
        flowLayout.itemSize.width = 194

        //If iPhone is 5(s)/SE, set width and height as shown below
    } else if screenWidth == 320 && screenHeight == 568 {
        flowLayout.itemSize.height = 147.5
        flowLayout.itemSize.width = 147.5
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not check against device types. Look at the screen size. You can readily do that through the UIScreen class.